# call Form2 from Form1 in wpf vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net

if in vb.net, I can call like this form2.show (), but how in wpf vb.net?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the Object Oriented method:

```
Dim f2 as New Form2
f2.Show()
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here in Wpf we cannot open/show the other form directly.
so in Wpf we have to create an object that refer to the form2.
because in Wpf even our form is considered as class.

```
Dim objForm2 As New Form2

objForm2.Show()
```